# Python: can not delete folder on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have created a folder named test6 at "C:/Users/minht/Documents/workspace/GG/ForexCBM/test6". Before I tried to delete that folder with a python script, I can manually delete the folder. It is just a normal empty directory. I can open the folder, check security properties ( right-click -> Properties -> security tab ) and change permissions.

But after running a python script (`python delete.py`) to delete, it is still there, and I can't even delete that folder manually. Also, I am unable to open that empty directory and check permission information. My Windows account is already administrator.

Here is my delete.py:

```
import shutil
import os
import stat

path = "C:/Users/minht/Documents/workspace/GG/ForexCBM/test6"

os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)

print("File deleted")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using chmod flags might be a bit complicated, in my opinion. I find easier to use permissions integer in octal:

```
import shutil
import os
import stat

path = "C:/Users/minht/Documents/workspace/GG/ForexCBM/test6"

os.chmod(path, 0o777)
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)

print("File deleted")
```

EDIT:

I've realised that you are asking for Windows way of deleting and I gave you Unix way. Here is Windows to change owner permissions:

```
import shutil
import os
import stat

path = "C:/Users/minht/Documents/workspace/GG/ForexCBM/test6" 

os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False)

print("File deleted")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes, it works. Since, My script has to run on both linux and window.I will use chmod bassed on the OS.Can you please tell me why I am getting such kind of error and how it is different between window and linux in getting the permission to delete folder.

Comment: Well, you were using Unix permission (stat.S_IWRITE) on Windows. You should have used "stat.S_IWUSR", Windows environment equivalent. Also, I've checked and learnt that only "write" permissions are sufficient for deleting folders and folder trees. Live and learn, huh? https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html

Comment: This is an old hack that Python has borrowed from Microsoft's C runtime. It's mapping write permission to the readonly file attribute, which is not a permission at all. Actually the right to delete a file in Unix or Windows has nothing to do with write permissions on the file or directory. In Unix it depends on the [i]mmutable file attribute in combination with write permission on the parent directory. In Windows it depends on the [r]eadonly file attribute in combination with either delete-child permission on the parent directory or delete permission on the file itself.